# How to download and store file from url on sdcard without need of scanning sdcard in android

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdcard

I am facing a problem in android emulator.

In my app i want to download image from url and stored in to sd card.

I am able to download and store the images on sdcard but there is one problem ?

When i download the images and store them, when I want to see that on sdcard gallary I cant see them. But when i scan the sdcard from dev tools-->Media Provider--Scan sdcard .
I got the images.

But dont want to scan sdcard in this way every time?
How to avoid it?
any suggetion?

Answer (score 0):

Use [MediaScanner.scanFile()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener%29) to notify the system of the new files.

Answer (score 0):

If you post your code snippet we may give some suggestion

It depends on how you are giving **sdcard** path to save the downloaded image